# How to count unique values in R while ignoring NAs

Tags: r, data.table

This is my input data

```
key     col_a      col_b      
  a       QQQ       <NA>    
  a       QQC       <NA>    
  b      <NA>        ACQ    
  b      <NA>        ACQ
```

I'd like to create this output

```
  key     col_a      col_b      
    a         2          0    
    b         0          1
```

I tried to do this with length(unique(x$col_a)) but it counts the NA as values

I'm creating this object with data.tables and it comes from an ifelse() statement.

Can I change the value I'm putting in the ifelse statement to something else or count unique ignoring NAs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For each `key` we can find out unique values in columns with `n_distinct`

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(key) %>%
  summarise(across(col_a:col_b, n_distinct, na.rm = TRUE))
```

---

In `data.table` this can be done as :

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, lapply(.SD, uniqueN, na.rm = TRUE), key, .SDcols = col_a:col_b]

   key col_a col_b
1:   a     2     0
2:   b     0     1
```

Comment: Awesome, I'll note that n_distinct also has `na.rm=T`

Comment: That is even better. Thanks. I updated the answer to include that.

Comment: What is .SD in the second part?

Comment: In `data.table` you can specify the columns you want to apply a function on with `.SDcols`. In `lapply`, we use `.SD` to refer those columns.

Answer (score 0):

We can use `base R` methods for this

```
aggregate(. ~ key, df, FUN = function(x)
      length(unique(na.omit(x))), na.action = NULL)
#    key col_a col_b
#1   a     2     0
#2   b     0     1
```

---

Or with `tidyverse` using anonymous function

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
     group_by(key) %>% 
     summarise(across(everything(), ~ n_distinct(., na.rm = TRUE)))
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(key = c("a", "a", "b", "b"), col_a = c("QQQ", 
"QQC", NA, NA), col_b = c(NA, NA, "ACQ", "ACQ")),
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))
```